# Как реализовать соединение компьютер-компьютер в JAVA?

Tags: java, сервер, tcp, client

Всем привет! Хочу реализовать соединение компьютер-компьютер. Уровень - самоучка. Допустим у меня есть программа (игра, например, танчики, крестики-нолики), рассчитанная на двоих человек.

Как мне реализовать взаимосвязь между этими двумя компьютерами, у которых динамические ip-адреса. Читал, что для этого нужен внешний сервер.

Каким он должен быть, если, например игра рассчитана на двух человек, а игру запустили больше двух. Нужно обеспечить взаимосвязанные пары компьютеров-клиентов, чтобы они не конфликтовали друг с другом?

Моего скудного опыта и понимания, а тем более знания не хватает для этой задачи, поэтому прошу помощи у знающих. Буду благодарен любой подсказки и помощи.

Comment: Думаю, Вам пригодится понимание сокетов. (Яндекс: java socket). Сокет-сервер + сокет клиент(ы). И решение станет ближе.

Comment: Меня интересует внешний сервер, как его правильно создать?

Comment: Внешний сервер. Вы хотите, чтобы в сети была точка, к которой мог бы подключиться любой пользователь. Вы пишете на Java. Решение: виртуальный выделенный сервер в digitalocean или в подобном сервисе. На виртуалке в сети поднимате свой сервер (либо свой с нуля сокет-сервер либо какой-нибудь REST-API на GlassFish или подобном контейнере с использованием того же SPRING'а), который будет либо отвечать за логику происходящего в игре, либо будет обеспечивать только обмен сигналами между клиентами, подключенными к нему.